Real analysis (series) practice questions.
I have an analysis 1 exam coming up this week, and I am still not particularly comfortable proving series convergence / divergence as well as continuity using the epsilon delta definition. I’m looking for books containing as many exercises as possible, preferably with solutions.

Actually, you can find many questions and solutions on this site with keywords.

Besides what @Bowei Tang said, you can also simply take a pencil/pen and pad of paper with you to your college/university library and look through the relevant sections for worked examples and exercises (especially those with answers provided) in the many (probably over $100)$ calculus and real analysis books on the library shelves. This has the advantage of replacing some of your screen time with another activity that still serves to prepare you for the test, which can make things less tedious (unless you like staring at a computer screen 10+ hours a day).

This response may be a little late now, but it may help you in the future, or others in the same scenario.
The first resource which I'd recommend is Paul's Online Math Notes, which covers Analysis I topics thoroughly. In particular, they have a whole section on series convergence and divergence, complete with practice problems (which have solutions) and assignment problems (which do not have solutions, simulating a test environment). You can find this section here:
https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Problems/CalcII/SeriesIntro.aspx
Secondly, not everyone knows that Oxford University makes their maths resources open source. This means that access is provided to lecture notes as well as problem sheets. Oxford offers a lecture course on Analysis I, providing numerous practice problems You can access these resources here:
https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=608
In terms of textbooks, I personally recommend Terence Tao's book on Analysis I. I worked through this in my first year of undergraduate mathematics, and I found it really useful for building up intuition. There are lots of exercises in the book, along with many theorems and lemmas with proofs. A great study method is to cover the proofs with a piece of paper and try to prove them yourself before checking the solution. This is a great way to build a deep understanding of the topic and to assess your comprehension. You can find the book here, though if applicable, I'm sure your university library will have this:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysis-I-Texts-Readings-Mathematics/dp/9380250649
Another excellent book is "Understanding Analysis" by Abbott, which includes many exercises and 150 additional exercises in the new edition. This book can be found here:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/1493927116
There are many resources available online, and in libraries. Therefore, the best thing to do is to try as many as necessary out, and find the one which resonates best with you.
Best of luck in your studies! If you have any other questions about these resources, feel free to ask.
